2005 PT Cruiser brake caliper sticking
2005 PT Cruiser brake caliper on the passenger side front keeps seizing up. How to fix? I have already taken it apart Grease the sleeves spray break cleaner over everything I'm trying not to have to buy a whole new caliber

Thankful for everyone that helped me out.  About 2 years ago I lost my father in law and mother in law in an accident and he was the mechanic and I was the jack ass son inlaw that took it for granted and I listened to him about 10% of the time and never knew that he was the glue that was keeping my family together.  So I truly appreciate the help it is not easy to fill a mans shoes and all of a sudden become mechanically inclined but I at least have some guidance in the world of back yard mechanical engineering..

Following standard safety precautions, raise the right front wheel enough that you can access the brake bleeder.
Step on the brake pedal hard, release it, then immediately go to the right front and momentarily loosen the brake bleeder. If brake fluid shoots out under high pressure, this confirms that the brake HOSE for that wheel has an internal fault and should be replaced.
This happens when the hose lining separates from the metal reinforcement and creates something like a one-way valve. Brake fluid passes toward the caliper but it returns to the master cylinder very slowly.
If you replace the hose, you'll have to bleed the brakes before putting the car back in service.

Your methodry seems like a great way to introduce air into the braking system.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Hmm, maybe; maybe not. If the hose is in fact bad, fluid will shoot out and no air will enter. If the hose is good, a small amount of fluid should drip out. In my experience, when the brake system is at rest and all is at equilibrium, the difference in height between the master cylinder and the brake bleeder creates a very small pressure at the bleeder - hydrostatic head pressure - and no air will enter. You get a slow dribble, not suction. Next time you set up to bleed a brake system and you'll be cracking the bleeders anyway, why not try this and see if you get the same results?
